# Creating a vector from user input data in a separate file(C++)

Tags: c++

Im working on a school project and need some help getting the framework figured out. Essentially Im trying to have the user read 4 survey questions, reply on a 1-10 point scale, save those answers and then average them, and then spit out an analysis for an average score of 1-4, 5-7, and 8+ and I need to use ifstream/ofstream with a separate file for the data or for the analysis. Here is the code I have so far

```
#include <fstream>  // for file I/O
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 using namespace std;
 //class definitions
  class Question {
  public:
    Question();
    Question(string query, int answer);
    int getAnswer() const;
    void setAnswer(int newAnswer);
    string getQuery() const ;
    double getAverage()const ;
    void setQuery(string newQuery);
  //    Question(string newQuery, int newAnswer);
    void print();
    void read();
    void read(ifstream&fin);
    void write(ofstream&fout);
private: 
    int Answer;
    string Query;
    double Average;
}; 
// Object Constructor
Question::Question(string newQuestion, int newAnswer) {
setQuery(Query);
setAnswer(Answer);
}       
string Question:: getQuery() const {
return Query;
}
int Question::getAnswer() const {
return Answer;
}
double Question::getAverage() const {
return Average;
}
void Question:: setQuery(string newQuery) {
Query= newQuery;
}
void Question:: setAnswer(int newAnswer) {
Answer= newAnswer;
}

//Question::Question(
// main function
int main() {
 ifstream fin;
 fin.open("quiz.txt");
 if ( fin.fail()) {
    cout << "Input file failed to open. \n";
    exit(-1);
 }       
  string line;
int answer;
int count = 1;
while(getline(fin, line)) {
    cout << line << endl;
    cin >>ws;
    cin>> answer; 
    count++;
}  

// Load data into a vector
vector<int> data;
int value;
while(fin >> value) {
    cout << value << endl;
    data.push_back(value);
}
fin.close();

// Process vector data
double sum = 0;
int count = data.size();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sum = sum + data[i];
}

cout << "average = " << (sum / count) << endl;


fin.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to show effort to solve the problem yourself first. For example, where are you trying to store the answers read from the user?

Comment: I have a separate file which contains all the 4 questions, I just need help figuring out how to connect those questions with user input data ( i know how to read the file, i have that written, i just cant figure out how to go from the user input data to storing it all separately and then adding up the numbers to find an average)

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<int>` to store the user's answers?

Comment: I was trying to use a vector to store the info, but I cant figure out how to connect the imported file into a vector, i get a "redefinition error" when i try to compile, i updated my original post to include the vector change

Comment: `cin>> answer;` You never do anything with the input answer.

Comment: Don't use `double` to sum a container of `int` (unless you expect the total to be huge, like billions). You can use the accumulate function: `int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: im not sure how to set up the int sum for accumulation? its not something ive done in class yet, and im not opposed to doing something new/different but i dont know what other code id need to put in to make it match up with what i have already

Comment: Replace your `double sum` variable with `int sum` and call the function, where you replace `v` with the name of the vector you want to add up all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you were trying to input numbers from a text file to a vector of integers. You would do it like this:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("numbers.txt")
vector<int> vec;
int number;
while(fin >> number)
vec.pushback(number);
fin.close();
```